# Splunk Query: Find the transactions that are taking more than 5 seconds

Tags: splunk, splunk-dashboard

Below is my search properties, Want add dashboard to show the transaction(transID, activity) that are having elapsedTime more than 5000

**2018-03-21 04:08:13.159-05:00  INFO - [http-/0.0.0.0:8080-4] |eventStartTime=2018-03-21 04:08:13.092 CDT|STATUS=SUCCESS|activity=POST->/xyz.com|eventElapsedTime=66|status=SUCCESS|transID=30d2e919-bd4d-4bad-a3c8-52cc69d10b43|eventEndTime=2018-03-21 04:08:13.159 CDT**

Comment: And a count of transactions (taking elapsedTime > 5000) also as another panel

Comment: So, what's the issue? Elaborate more on what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query for the transactions

```
index=f00 | where eventElapsedTime>5000 | table transID activity
```

and this one for the count

```
index=f00 | where eventElapsedTime>5000 | stats count
```

After running each search, click the Save As link to save the search in a dashboard panel.